# Grabbing key:values from JSON object in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to loop through the returned JSON and display images based on the results. I am able to pull the feed, but not sure where I'm going wrong on grabbing the `poster_path` from the results and appending to an `<img ng-src="">` path.

The JSON:

```
results: [
{
    poster_path: "/title-of-image.jpg",
    overview: "description of movie",
    release_date: "2016-08-03",
    id: 297761,
    original_language: "en",
    title: "Movie title",
    popularity: 44.788935,
    }
}
```

I'm looping through the object and able to view the results in the console, but can't grab the data correctly:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('demoController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=ebea8cfca72fdff8d2624ad7bbf78e4c")
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.results = response;
    });
});

<div class="container" ng-repeat="result in results">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumbnail" ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342" + {{result.poster_path}}></a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm seeing in the console:

Object {page: 1, results: Array[20], dates: Object, total_pages: 33, total_results: 654}

GET http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342 400 (Bad Request)

Results array expanded:
[image]

Comment: What do you think/expect `$scope.results.poster_path` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the output of your console.log(response), you will see that the data you want is actually in a property called results.

```
{page: 1, results: Array[20], dates: Object, total_pages: 33, total_results: 654}
```

So the data you want to look is actually response.results. Does that make sense? With that in mind, we want to have the following html snippet.

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="items in results">
      <img ng-src="http://www.source-to-image" + {{items.poster_path}}>
</div>
```

and then the following controller:

```
var movieapp = angular.module('movieapp', []);
myapp.controller('movieController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("http://www.url-to-source")
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.results = response.results;
    });
});
```

I can't tell what's in each poster_path, so let me know if this works.

Comment: Ah, this is closer. The issue now is that the image link construction is off. It's not appending the `items.poster_path` correctly to the image link.

Comment: Also, this solution is only pulling the first 5 items from the JSON response, where there should be 20.

Comment: No problem. I was guessing about your structure. Please post your current html snippet, your controller snippet, and what you're seeing from console log.

Comment: I've just updated the question with my current code and console output.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I think you were looping through response instead of response.results.

Comment: I've updated my code, but still getting the same issue. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the returned object with one of the results array items expanded.

Comment: I can't see the screen shot, but you can put you can do this.. (if you want to see what's being looped)... <div class="container" ng-repeat="items in results">
      {{items}} 
</div>

Comment: It's the last part of the question. Should be showing up now.

Comment: Ok.. I am not sure if you changed the controller, but it should be $scope.results = response.results. not $scope.results = response

Comment: Yes, I've updated my code earlier. That's not the problem anymore. I'm able to output the fields to the screen, but I can't append the value of one of the fields to the end of the base url for the images.

Comment: So the question is why I can't append `poster_path` to the end of the url, as I'm doing in my code right now: src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342' + {{items.poster_path}}.

Comment: I don't think you can do ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342" + {{result.poster_path}} it should be ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/{{result.poster_path}}"

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues.
First, you have forgotten that the `results` object in your response **is an array** (denoted by the square brackets []).

```
results: [
```

You must first get the object out of the array like so:

```
$http.get("http://www.url-to-source")
.success(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.results[0].poster_path);
});
```

Secondly, and more importantly, **you aren't doing anything with the data!**
This statement does absolutely nothing:

```
$scope.results.poster_path;
```

You aren't assigning anything to anything else. And what's worse, is that  `$scope.results` is not even defined at this point. So, you **should** be seeing an error like `cannot read property 'poster_path' of undefined`

Comment: I've updated my code before this and pulling results (forgot to update it in the question). The issue now is that I'm not able to append the `poster_path` from the JSON to the base url to construct the image path.